# Import from subfolder python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

My project structure is the following. Inside api.py i need some functions written in the upper level.

```
Project1
├── model.py 
├── audio_utils.py
├── audio.py 
└── backend
     ├── static
     │      ├──js
     │      ├──img
     └── api.py
```

Why am I unable to import inside api.py the functions in the upper level?
When i try to do:

```
from audio_utils import *
```

I got the following:

```
 No module named 'audio_utils'
```

Comment: Have you tried `from Project1.audio_utils import *`?

Comment: Can you check if the path project is in PYTHONPATH `python -c "import sys;print(sys.path);"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modules are imported from paths prefixes specified in `sys.path`. It usually contains `''` that means that modules from current working directory are gonna be loaded.
(https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages)

I think you are starting your Python interpret while being in the `backend` directory. Then I think there is no way to access the modules in the upper directory -- not even with the `..` (https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/#syntax-and-practical-examples_1) unless you change the `sys.path` which would be a really messy solution.

I suggest you create `__init__.py` files to indicate that the directories containing them are *Python packages*:

```
Project1
├── model.py 
├── audio_utils.py
├── audio.py 
└── backend
     |-- __init__.py
     ├── static
     │      ├──js
     │      ├──img
     └── api.py
```

And always start the interpret from the `Project1` dir. Doing so, you should be able to import any module like this:

```
import model
from backed import api
import audio_utils
```

no matter in which module in the `Project1` you are writing this in. The current directory **of the interpret** will be tried.

Note there is also the `PYTHONPATH` env variable and that you can use to your advantage.

Note that for *publishing* your project it is encouraged to put all the modules in a package (in other words: don't put the modues to the top level). This is to help prevent name collisions. I think this may help you to understand: https://realpython.com/pypi-publish-python-package/

Comment: Thanks! I created a new file in the top folder than imported the api form backend and launched the server as usual. It was not working before because my 'main' was inside the api.py

Answer (score 0):

If you create the dir structure this way:

```
$ tree
.
├── bar
│   ├── den.py
│   └── __init__.py  # This indicates the bar is python package.
└── baz.py

1 directory, 3 files
$ cat bar/den.py 
import baz
```

Then in the dir containing the `bar/` and `baz.py` (the top level) you can start the Python interpret and use the absolute imports:

```
In [1]: import bar.den                                                                                                                                                                        

In [2]: import baz                                                                                                                                                                            

In [3]: bar.den.baz                                                                                                                                                                           
Out[3]: <module 'baz' from '/tmp/Project1/baz.py'>
```

As you can see, we were able to import `bar.den` which also could import the `baz` from the top-level.